# Soap film bursting dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Suppose I form a soap water film on a circular frame and poke a hole(with a pinhead) in the center, how will the circular hole formed increase in size with time (as the soap film bursts)? and does the shape of the frame and where I poke the hole affect the growth of the hole? And can I always consider the hole to be circular?

Comment: Google "soap bubble pop slow motion" and watch.

Answer (score 0):

According to [(Taylor 1959)](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1959.0196) ([pdf](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1959.0196?casa_token=hxLLHEKC85wAAAAA:QvFIXU_7uLtQKGTVeumQurQHDZpFyDHMB4j_RadJZNy_C6_uuDNf5gP1piwJYfbTSyg_oF7mAo0uOf8)) if you have a uniform soap sheet, the free edge moves with velocity $$v_r = \sqrt{\frac{2T}{\rho t}}$$ where $T$ is the surface tension, $\rho$ the density and $t$ the thickness of the sheet. ([Culick 1960](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1735765)) points out that this is what you get if you include energy conservation and that the liquid from the punctured area now is piling up along the edge.

If the frame is big and flat the shape should not matter at all. I also *think* that since the film is a minimal surface that gives the same local tension at any point, and hence the initial hole will be circular. For non-planar frames the hole will of course start to bend as it expands, following the surface.

Looking (and listening) carefully at small bubbles popping ([Bussonniere et al. 2020](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.124.084502)) ([pdf](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.124.084502?casa_token=yIkYOUxOmuQAAAAA%3A2QkrX2zWdgsCBIUYOAgBw7HNni6nTT87vBTUOsA1AY67BZc0NN9hCVgZOWLR6RO9OklHl5kSJRWP_TA)) show that there is also a shock wave moving faster than the retraction wave along the surface of the bubble. Their pictures also show that after about 2 ms the rim is starting to fragment into a "crown" with droplets: surface tension instabilities will try to make the piled up liquid into droplets, complicating things a lot.